# Is there operator for ‘apply operation for each subset of a given set’?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

There exist well known [set operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets). For example Union: $\{1,2\} \cup \{2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$

I am interested in extension of these operations in the following way (I have used `*operation` just for illustrations):

$A = \{\{1,2\}, \{1,2,4\}\}$

$A *\cup \{2,3\} = \{a \in A: a \cup \{2,3\}\} = \{\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2,3,4\}\}$

$A *\setminus \{2,3\} = \{a \in A: a \setminus \{2,3\}\} =\{\{1\}, \{1,4\}\}$

Somethig similar to convolution. Apply operation to every item in a set.

Is there name and notation for such operations in Set Theory? I want to learn more about this type of operations.

> the empirical observation that one can manipulate expressions in the
> algebra of sets, by translating them into expressions in [Boole's
> algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Is it possible to translate $*\cup$ and $*∩$ into expression in Boole's algebra?

In Python it is called List Comprehensions: `b = [a+2 for a in [1,2,3]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct notation is $\{a\setminus\{2,3\}\mid a\in A\}$ (or $:$ instead of $\mid$ if you prefer it that way).

There is no standard notation like $A*\setminus\{2,3\}$ or so, nor there should be, the above notation is perfectly clear and fairly compact.

If your function gets much more complicated, then you'd normally just give it a compact notation (e.g. $f$ or $\varphi$ or whatnot) and then, depending on your context, you can write $f(A)$, $f[A]$, or $f``A$ to mean $\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$. Or you might just write $\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$.

Comment: I was interested in Algebraic point of view. For example I can translate set operations to Boole's algebra. Is it possible to translate for example *U?

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen $f``$ notation before. That's a new one for me!

Comment: @Oleg: I don't understand your concern. You want to apply an operation to a bunch of sets. Where's the difficulty, then?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: It's very common in set theory.

Comment: Hah I suspected as much given that you were the one to share it. I haven't done too much beyond naive set theory in courses here or there.